# Can we have a part of a scrollable Listview (implemented using hashmap) non-scrollable?

Tags: android

Im using textview and edittexts to make a listview and using a hashmap to copy paste the layout. Now how do i get the values from the edit texts ? I tried it but it doesn't work because everytime we're using a new hashmap variable to create a copy and i didn't find anything like an array of hashmap variables.. Help needed.
My xml files :

MarksList>res>layout>marks_list_main :

Comment: Question title and description are not same.Do you need the value of edit text from the list view?

Comment: Yes.. Sorry 4 the inconvenience. Wanted to ask 2 different questions.. combined both..!! And yes I want the values of the edittexts from the listview

Comment: Don't know how formed your list.See the answer to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have added a LinearLayout as list item and on that Layout there is an edittext and a textview

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) listView.getItemAtPosition(0);
EditText text = (EditText) layout.getChildAt(0); //Assuming you added EditText first
String s=text.getText().toString()
```